# What does LLDB stand for?

Tags: ios, debugging, lldb

What does LLDB ,debugger in xcode, stand for? 
Is it something like "low level debugger"? 
Googled it, however couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Presumably, yes, as LLVM is for Low Level Virtual Machine

Comment: I would guess 'LLVM Debugger'

Comment: Yes, we debated this a bit at first, since lldb IS the debugger of the LLVM project but lldb is NOT a low-level debugger particularly...  So the "LL" part shouldn't be parsed too carefully, but rather should be considered more of an honorific...

Answer (score 12):

As per the Xcode Debugging course on Udacity, LLDB stands for **L**ow **L**evel **D**e**b**ugger

Link to the course - https://www.udacity.com/course/xcode-debugging--ud774
(Mentioned in the 2nd slide of Lesson 3)

Answer (score 4):

LLDB is the debugger component of the Clang/LLVM compiler toolchain.

Check here: http://lldb.llvm.org/

Answer (score 2):

#### `LLDB` (low-level debugger) is part of `LLVM`

The LLVM compiler (low level virtual machine) creates programming languages. LLDB is Apple’s “from the ground up” replacement for GDB.

The LLDB debugger is analogous to GDB: (The GNU Project Debugger).

Both work on many Unix-like systems and works for many programming languages

#### Each below support debugging programs written in the languages below

[GDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger):  Ada, C, C++, Objective-C, Free Pascal, Fortran, Go, and partially others

[LLDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)): C, Objective-C, and C++. Also, the Swift community maintains a version which adds support for the language.

Comment: BTW: Both have very similar commands, some exactly the same

Comment: LLVM was originally developed as a research infrastructure to investigate dynamic compilation techniques for static and dynamic programming languages. ... The name LLVM was originally an initialism for Low Level Virtual Machine. Whereas GDB was first written by Richard Stallman for The GNU Project (GNU + Linux Kernel = Linux)
See: https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.en.html